# Long Ajax error using Date module Views and Fullcalendar

Tags: views, datetime, javascript

I have searched for many posts and i am already doing the suggestions. Nothing is fixing this.

Fullcalendar module says to use the "use ajax" option within views but it throws a huge error.

[image]

> Notice: Undefined index: date in date_text_element_process() (line 322 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date_api_elements.inc).
>
> [{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"M0zPUqa2WJ22nPMH1OUnLDQwPXU0b8nwseud8PJfMbg","jquery_version":"1.7"},"urlIsAjaxTrusted":{"/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/event_calendar/page/use_ajax":true}},"merge":true},{"command":"viewsDismissForm"},{"command":"viewsShowButtons","changed":true},{"command":"viewsTriggerPreview"},{"command":"insert","method":"html","selector":"#views-tab-page","data":"\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-details\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-top\u0022 class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-actions views-ui-display-tab-bucket clearfix\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-button ctools-dropbutton\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022horizontal right actions\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022duplicate\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022clone Artist Show Schedule Page\u0022 class=\u0022form-submit\u0022 /\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022delete\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022delete Artist Show Schedule Page\u0022 class=\u0022form-submit\u0022 /\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022disable\u0022\u003E\u003Cinput type=\u0022submit\u0022 name=\u0022op\u0022 value=\u0022disable Artist Show Schedule Page\u0022 class=\u0022form-submit\u0022 /\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EDisplay name:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/display_title\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Artist Show Schedule Page\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-display-title\u0022\u003EArtist Show Schedule Page\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-display-settings-main\u0022 class=\u0022clearfix views-display-columns\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-column first\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket title\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003ETitle\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting overridden even clearfix\u0022  title=\u0022Overridden\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003ETitle:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/title\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change the title that this display will use.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-title\u0022\u003EShow Schedule\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket format\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EFormat\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting overridden odd clearfix\u0022  title=\u0022Overridden\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EFormat:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/style_plugin\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change the way content is formatted.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-style-plugin\u0022\u003EFullCalendar\u003C/a\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003E\u0026nbsp;|\u0026nbsp;\u003C/span\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/style_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link views-button-configure\u0022 title=\u0022Change settings for this format\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-style-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan\u003ESettings\u003C/span\u003E\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket fields overridden\u0022  title=\u0022Overridden\u0022\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-1\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/field\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-field\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/rearrange/event_calendar/page/field\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-field\u0022\u003ERearrange\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003EFields\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-field-title even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/field/title\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Title\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-field-field-event-date odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/field/field_event_date\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Event Date\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-field-field-event-description even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/field/field_event_description\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Event Description\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-field-field-where odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/field/field_where\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Where\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket filter-criteria\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-2\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/filter\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-filter\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/rearrange-filter/event_calendar/page/filter\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-filter\u0022\u003EAnd/Or, Rearrange\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003EFilter criteria\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-filter-status even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/filter/status\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Published (Yes)\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-filter-type odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/filter/type\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Type (= Calendar Artist Shows)\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket sort-criteria\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-3\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/sort\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-sort\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/rearrange/event_calendar/page/sort\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-sort\u0022\u003ERearrange\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003ESort criteria\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-sort-created even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/sort/created\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Post date (desc)\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-column second\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket page-settings\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EPage settings\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EPath:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/path\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022/users/%/Show-Schedule\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-path\u0022\u003E/users/%/Show-Schedule\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EMenu:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/menu\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022No menu\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-menu\u0022\u003ENo menu\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket access\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting overridden odd clearfix\u0022  title=\u0022Overridden\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EAccess:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/access\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Specify access control type for this display.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-access\u0022\u003ERole\u003C/a\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003E\u0026nbsp;|\u0026nbsp;\u003C/span\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/access_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link views-button-configure\u0022 title=\u0022Change settings for this access type.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-access-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan\u003EArtist\u003C/span\u003E\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket header\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-4\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/header\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-header\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003EHeader\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket footer\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-5\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/footer\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-footer\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003EFooter\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket pager\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EPager\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EUse pager:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/pager\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change this display\u0026#039;s pager setting.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-pager\u0022\u003EDisplay all items\u003C/a\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003E\u0026nbsp;|\u0026nbsp;\u003C/span\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/pager_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link views-button-configure\u0022 title=\u0022Change settings for this pager type.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-pager-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan\u003EAll items\u003C/span\u003E\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EMore link:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/use_more\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Specify whether this display will provide a \u0026quot;more\u0026quot; link.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-use-more\u0022\u003ENo\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-column third ctools-collapsible-container ctools-collapsible-remember ctools-collapsed\u0022 id=\u0022views-ui-advanced-column-event_calendar\u0022\u003E\u003Ch3 class=\u0022ctools-collapsible-handle\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\u0022\u003EAdvanced\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/h3\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-collapsible-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket contextual-filters\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-6\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/argument\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-argument\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/rearrange/event_calendar/page/argument\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-argument\u0022\u003ERearrange\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003EContextual filters\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-argument-uid even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/argument/uid\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003E(author) User: Uid\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket relationships\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-dropbutton ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-7\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-link\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022#\u0022 class=\u0022ctools-twisty ctools-text\u0022\u003Eopen\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/relationship\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-relationship\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003Cli class=\u0022rearrange last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/rearrange/event_calendar/page/relationship\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact rearrange views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Rearrange\u0022 id=\u0022views-rearrange-relationship\u0022\u003ERearrange\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003ERelationships\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting page-relationship-uid odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/event_calendar/page/relationship/uid\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link\u0022\u003EContent: Author\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket no-results-behavior\u0022 \u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-no-js ctools-button views-ui-settings-bucket-operations\u0022 id=\u0022ctools-button-8\u0022\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022ctools-content\u0022\u003E\u003Cul class=\u0022actions horizontal right\u0022\u003E\u003Cli class=\u0022add first last\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/add-item/event_calendar/page/empty\u0022 class=\u0022icon compact add views-ajax-link\u0022 title=\u0022Add\u0022 id=\u0022views-add-empty\u0022\u003EAdd\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/li\u003E\n\u003C/ul\u003E\u003C/div\u003E\u003C/div\u003E        \u003Ch3\u003ENo results behavior\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket exposed-form\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EExposed form\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EExposed form in block:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/exposed_block\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Allow the exposed form to appear in a block instead of the view.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-exposed-block\u0022\u003ENo\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EExposed form style:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/exposed_form\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Select the kind of exposed filter to use.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-exposed-form\u0022\u003EBasic\u003C/a\u003E\u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003E\u0026nbsp;|\u0026nbsp;\u003C/span\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/exposed_form_options\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link views-button-configure\u0022 title=\u0022Exposed form settings for this exposed form style.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-exposed-form-options\u0022\u003E\u003Cspan\u003ESettings\u003C/span\u003E\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-ui-display-tab-bucket other\u0022 \u003E\n          \u003Ch3\u003EOther\u003C/h3\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EMachine Name:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/display_id\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change the machine name of this display.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-display-id\u0022\u003Epage\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EComment:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/display_comment\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Comment or document this display.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-display-comment\u0022\u003ENo comment\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting overridden even clearfix\u0022  title=\u0022Overridden\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EUse AJAX:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/use_ajax\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change whether or not this display will use AJAX.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-use-ajax\u0022\u003ENo\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted odd clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EHide attachments in summary:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/hide_attachment_summary\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change whether or not to display attachments when displaying a contextual filter summary.\u0022 id=\u0022views-page-hide-attachment-summary\u0022\u003ENo\u003C/a\u003E  \u003C/div\u003E\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022views-display-setting views-ui-display-tab-setting defaulted even clearfix\u0022 \u003E\n      \u003Cspan class=\u0022label\u0022\u003EHide contextual links:\u003C/span\u003E\n        \u003Ca href=\u0022/admin/structure/views/nojs/display/event_calendar/page/hide_admin_links\u0022 class=\u0022views-ajax-link \u0022 title=\u0022Change whether or n

Answer (score 0):

In installations instructions it says you need to [download this plugin](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/download/v1.6.7/fullcalendar-1.6.7.zip)

- Unzip the plugin.
- Upload the **fullcalendar** folder to `/sites/all/libraries`

So in the end you should have `/sites/all/libraries/fullcalendar/`

You may need to manually create the `/libraries` folder inside `/all` folder if you haven't done this before.

Comment: I am beyond this step. Ive follow all of their instruction.

Comment: Did you download v1.6.7 of the plugin? It says that version 2 is not compatible.

Comment: yes i am using all recommended settings according to the module page and the readme.txt

Comment: Try updating jQuery to 1.11 ?

Comment: If you can get [TeamView](http://twww.teamviewer.com) I'd be glad to try and help you remotely.

Comment: check your status report `/admin/reports/status` and `/admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: 1.11 isnt an option with jquery update module. 1.10 is the highest. and that doesn't solve it

Comment: ok try 1.10 then

Comment: I did no changes at all. Hard to believe I'm the only one who experienced this.

Comment: which makes me think that you did one of the installation steps wrong.

Comment: Shane Thomas from codeKarate has a tutorial video that i followed and he was getting the same error. He brushed over it and never explained why or how to fix it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj62mcHE2EM

Comment: Then do what Shane did, he turned off ajax (**Use Ajax: No**)

Comment: He explains that at 10:51 of the video...

Comment: That is a direct conflict with what the module page says. For performance issues they say to turn it on.

Comment: Try using the 7.x-2.x-dev version of Full Calendar instead.